# Parse multiple APIs in Python and match values that have different keys

Tags: python, json, api, python-dataclasses

In Python, I am working on a web version of an exotic cookbook, fetching recipes from various APIs so as to publish it to a new web site.

How can I map about 100 different JSON structures to mine ?

Do I have to do it manually as I show in this example with "get_content_from_api_1", "...2" and so on, or is there a better way ?

Is there a way with sqlAlchemy to make things easier as opposed to native PostgreSql ?

Constraints I face :

- the various APIs do not share the same structure at all
- Some APIs will have non-flat structures
- There will be about 100 different APIs, so 100 different structures and key names

A working example of the code I have :

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import requests


@dataclass
class MyCookingData:
    chocolate: str
    cucumber: str = None
    loaf: str = None


sample_obj_1 = {
    "chocolate": "dark",
    "cucumber": "long and green",
    "loaf": "2 pounds",
}

sample_obj_2 = {
    "choco": "milk",
    "cuc": "5",
    "meatloaf": "juicy",
}


def fetch_the_api(url):
    '''Fetch a public url, but return sample objects for the example'''
    '''
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print(err)
    '''
    response = url # sample_obj_ 1 and 2 for the example
    return response

def get_content_from_api_1(url):
    '''Get url or sample object 1'''
    api_data = fetch_the_api(url)
    new_data = MyCookingData(
        chocolate=api_data['chocolate'],
        cucumber=api_data['cucumber'],
        loaf=api_data['loaf'],
    )
    populate_db(new_data)

def get_content_from_api_2(url):
    '''Get url or sample object 2'''
    api_data = fetch_the_api(url)
    new_data = MyCookingData(
        chocolate=api_data['choco'],
        cucumber=api_data['cuc'],
        loaf=api_data['meatloaf'],
    )
    populate_db(new_data)

def populate_db(data):
    '''Store in db, but print for example'''
    # print(data.__dict__)
    for each_elem in data.__dict__:
        print(each_elem, '=>', data.__dict__[each_elem])


def main():
    print('Get content from API 1:')
    get_content_from_api_1(sample_obj_1)
    print('************')
    print('Get content from API 2:')
    get_content_from_api_2(sample_obj_2)
    print('************')


main()
```

The result I get from running this code is :

```
Get content from API 1:
chocolate => dark
cucumber => long and green
loaf => 2 pounds
************
Get content from API 2:
chocolate => milk
cucumber => 5
loaf => juicy
************
```

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps could provide a bit more background info, and perhaps some code that you've tried and had problems with - check out the SO guidelines

Having said that, you're possibly better off to look at `pydantic` rather than dataclasses (or perhaps pydantic's versions of dataclasses).

Dataclasses by themselves will not do anything for parsing input (though there are modules that can build in dataclasses to do that), nor will they do anything to validate types etc.  Pydantic in contrast will do all those things for you if you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check out pydantic dataclasses. I also added 2 of 100 or so functions I have to work with. It seems redundant to me and I'm sure there has to be a better way. Background info is I am working on an exotic cookbook and fetching ingredients and recipes APIs so as to publish it in a new web site.

Comment: Thank you rv.kvetch , I reworded my issue and provided a tested MRE. Hopefully I explain myself better.

Comment: @paulavan It looks like you might need to use field aliases such as what pydantic offers. For example, you want to map a common field like `chocolate` to differently named fields in each API, like `choco` or `choc`? If that's the case, and if each API has the same schema essentially (not sure if it's the case though), then it should be possible to define a single model class, albeit with multiple aliases that map to each field.